# Reporting Multiple Values in One Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am still wading my way through SQL (I feel like I'll be doing this forever!)

I'm trying to select customers and show all the places they've traveled to, which could be more than 1, and have them listed in columns by year.

Example:

```
name    2014    2015      2016
bob     japan   korea     Mexico
        Tucson  England   
Dennis  Paris   England   China
        Texas   Canada
                Portland
```

I've got:

```
SELECT name, 
     (SELECT location from places where year = '2014') AS '2014',
     (SELECT location from places where year = '2015') AS '2015',
     (SELECT location from places where year = '2014') AS '2016'
FROM customer
JOIN places 
on places.customerID = customer.customerID
```

Sorry for the pseudo-code; I'm traveling now but this has been bugging me for days. I feel like my syntax or approach is wrong...

Many thanks for the guidance!

Comment: There's no 'feel' about it - it either functions as expected or not. I suspect you will get a 'subquery returns more than one value' error when you run this but it appears you haven't actually run it yet? What you're after here is a crosstab.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid ahh! Yes! I'll hopefully be able to connect and run it! I think I'll get that error too. Oh! Crosstab! Thank you for the point in that direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you  are going to have with the query you wrote is that SQL Server will complain if you try to use a sub-query as an expression and it returns more than one record.  You'll see the error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= ,> >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

In your case, you're using subqueries as expressions in your main select statement.

Your output is something you would generally want to accomplish in your reporting or application layer.  It's not something SQL is great at, but possible.  However one thing that could help is to generate a field that contains the list of the places per customer and year. The FOR XML clause is good at condensing many values into lists or xml values.  Below is an example where it creates a comma separated list of the locations, but you can use any delimiter you like.

```
create table #customer (customerID int, name varchar(50))
create table #places (customerID int, year int, location varchar(50))

insert into #customer values (1, 'Bob')
insert into #customer values (2, 'Dennis')

insert into #places values (1, 2014, 'Japan')
insert into #places values (1, 2014, 'Tucon')
insert into #places values (2, 2014, 'Paris')
insert into #places values (2, 2014, 'Texas')
insert into #places values (1, 2015, 'Korea')
insert into #places values (1, 2015, 'England')
insert into #places values (2, 2015, 'England')
insert into #places values (2, 2015, 'Canada')
insert into #places values (2, 2015, 'Portland')
insert into #places values (1, 2016, 'Mexico')
insert into #places values (2, 2016, 'China')

select name, year,
    STUFF(
        (select ',' + location
        from #places 
        where #places.customerID = c.customerID
            and #places.year = p.year
        for XML Path('')
        ) 
        , 1, 1, ''
    ) AS locations
FROM #customer c
JOIN #places p
on p.customerID = c.customerID
group by c.name, c.customerID, p.year
```

Then from this data format you can do something more like your query above because the location is just one value per customer/year combination.  You can also use the `PIVOT` functionality in SQL Server, but once again you might also be able to do this in your reporting layer.  For example using pivoting functions in Excel, Reporting Services... etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation with `ROW_NUMBER` to achieve the desired result:

```
;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT c.name,p.*,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.customerID, p.year ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
    FROM customer c
    INNER JOIN places p
        ON p.customerID = c.customerID
)
SELECT
    name    = CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN name ELSE '' END,
    [2014]  = MAX(CASE WHEN c.year = '2014' THEN c.location ELSE '' END),
    [2015]  = MAX(CASE WHEN c.year = '2015' THEN c.location ELSE '' END),
    [2016]  = MAX(CASE WHEN c.year = '2016' THEN c.location ELSE '' END)
FROM Cte c
GROUP BY c.customerID, c.name, c.rn
ORDER BY c.name, c.customerID
```

<kbd>[**TRY IT HERE**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/441790)</kbd>

Comment: this works really well, I didn't know about ROW_NUMBER() thanks!